# Is it OK to run the WHILE loops in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it ok to a mysql query inside a while loop using the ID of each row passed to fetch results from another table?  OR is there a better way to do it?

```
$q = $__FROG_CONN__->query("SELECT cms_page.id, cms_page.title, cms_page.slug, cms_page_part.* FROM cms_page LEFT JOIN cms_page_part ON cms_page_part.page_id=cms_page.id WHERE cms_page.parent_id='8'");
$r = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo '<ul id="project-list">';
  foreach ($r as $row) { 
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a href="'.$row["slug"].'.html"><img src="<img src="phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=public/images/'.$row[0].'/th.jpg&w=162" alt="" /></a>';
    echo '<div class="p-text">';
    echo '<h4>'.$row["location"].'<span>'.$row["project_date"].'</span></h4>';
    echo '<p>'.$row["body"].'</p>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</li>';
  }
echo '</ul>';
```

I am trying to pull the project_date, body and location fields from another table where the sql query matches.  The title and slug are held in another table.  There should only be a maximum of eight or so results but im getting alot more.

Comment: Where do the ids come from? Are your users entering rowids directly into the user interface, or are you getting them from another query?

Comment: question title is too general

Comment: What is your "inner" query? I only see one query here.

Comment: Im using the join to try and combine the results...after the posts below...

Comment: What is what you wanted to get? Could you please post some sample data and the resultset you want to get?

Comment: @Andy: While it's good that you have posted your non-working query in the question, your question title and description don't match with the problem with your posted code. This will just confuse everyone.

Comment: Sorry, i started off asking a simple question to see if i could sidestep my major issue with joins!  But its scaled out of control a little :@(  Sorry to confuse everyone, that wasnt my intention.

Comment: ive edited my cdode again to hopefully describe it better....

Comment: I think your problem is that you have multiple page_parts per page and this is causing each row in the LEFT table to be returned once for each row in the RIGHT table. This is how SQL works. If a cms_page can only have one location, why is the location column in the cms_page_part table and not in the cms_page table? I think either your data model is wrong, or else you are trying to query for something that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your question is still too vague. What is "another table" with the `project_date` and `body`? What is "another table" with the `title` and the `slug`? Is it the same table or two tables? Could you please just post the scripts of the relevant tables (use `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename`), some data in them and the results you want to get?

Comment: What you just described is exactly the issue.  Thanks!!! However i didnt created this CMS.  and im way to far through this to change database design.  IS there any options for me?

Comment: To expand on my previous post: your query is similar to querying where a car is made by querying for where each part of the car was made. Since the different car parts may have been made in different countries the question does not make sense in general. You could however choose one specific component such as the engine and define the assembly location of the engine to be place where the car was made. Similarly, you could choose one specific part in your page and define the location for that part as the location for your entire page.

Comment: I understand your example but i'm not sure i understand if there is a solution :@)

Comment: Im thinking a foreach loop inside a while loop is my only option, which brings my back to the original question!

Comment: The solution is to choose one of the parts to join with and get the location from that. It doesn't matter which part you choose, as long as you only choose one. Always choose the first one for example.

Answer (score 3):

The suggestions using IN are fine, but if you are getting the ids from another query, it might be better to combine these two queries into one query using a join.

Instead of:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE age <30
SELECT id, x FROM userinfo WHERE userid IN ($id1, $id2, ..., $idn)
```

do:

```
SELECT users.id, userinfo.x
FROM users
LEFT JOIN userinfo ON userinfo.userid = users.id
WHERE age < 30
```

Comment: Ive edited my code...to show you that i was using a join and its not working for me...not sure what ive done wrong...i get the four results for each portfolio printed in a list (that is four results of the page part table which exists for each portfolio)

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the overhead of preforming a query, you may want to look at getting all the data in a single query. In which case you may want to take a look at IN(), e.g.

```
SELECT * WHERE x IN (1, 2);
```

There is also BETWEEN()

```
SELECT * WHERE x BETWEEN 1 AND 2;
```

See the [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html) for more information

Comment: im fetching results from two tables but i need to carry to the ID from to the other to make sure i pull the associated rows...so WHERE isnt really involved i dont think!

Comment: @Andy In that case a JOIN may be what you are looking for.

Comment: I tried a join...

$q = $__FROG_CONN__->query("SELECT cms_page.id, cms_page.title, cms_page.slug, cms_page_part.* FROM cms_page LEFT JOIN cms_page_part ON cms_page_part.page_id=cms_page.id WHERE cms_page.parent_id='8'");

It just gives me loads of results...including all the combined page parts im after but not as single rows

Comment: Still, it sounds like a JOIN is what you are after. Look up the documentation on differents types of JOINs (INNER, OUTER, etc.) and ask a more precise question on JOINs if you cannot figure out how to get the results that you are after.

Comment: I think the join is the right method too (I even posted this as an answer). You should try to understand why your join isn't working rather than ignoring the problem and choosing instead to solve the problem in an inefficient manner.

Answer (score 0):

In a small application / small result set, this might be okay, but it results in a lot of (small) calls to the database.

If you can find an alternative way (perhaps see [Yacoby's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958290/while-loop-question/1958298#1958298)?) in which you can do one call to the database, this is probably better.

**EDIT**

If you are only interested in the IDs from one table, in order to get the correct results out of another table, perhaps a JOIN is what you are looking for?

```
SELECT t1.fieldA, t1.fieldB
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t2.someField = 'someValue'
```

Comment: I need the results from both tables combined to one row...so i could call $r["table1colum2"] or $r["table2colum3"] but from the same $r

Comment: That is exactly what the JOIN can do for you: `SELECT * ...` will select all columns from both tables, or you can select specific columns from the two tables: `SELECT t1.fieldA, t2.fieldX FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID`

Answer (score 0):

I would try to build the query in a way where I only need to pass it once. Something like WHERE ID=1 OR ID=2 OR ... Passing multiple queries and returning multiple recordsets is expensive in terms of processing and network traffic.

Comment: Yeh i thought this was the case but i dont know a better way of doing it...the where clause just doesnt cover what im trying to do unforuntately.  I wish it did!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it ok to a mysql query inside a while loop using the ID of each row passed to fetch results from another table? OR is there a better way to do it?

You should reformulate your query in `SQL`. Say, put the `id`s into a memory table and use it in a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    idtable
JOIN    mytable
ON      mytable.id = idtable.id
```

This way, `MySQL` will make the loops for you but will make them in (usually) more efficient way.

`SQL` is a language designed to work with sets.

So if you have a set of `id`s and a table (which is a set of tuples), your first thought should be "how do I apply the set-based operations to these sets using `SQL`"?

Of course it is possible to run a bunch of simple queries in a loop but this way you just do extra work which `SQL` engine developers most probably have already done for you (and usually have done it in more efficient way).

You may want to read this article in my blog:

- [**Double-thinking in SQL**](http://explainextended.com/2009/07/12/double-thinking-in-sql/)

Answer (score 0):

This will be very inefficient, what you want is to join the tables on the ID

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON (table1.ID = table2.ID) WHERE condition
```

[Mysql join documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

This will return one set of rows with all the information you need, returned from both tables.